# Select templated operator implementation

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose we have an `operator/` on custom class:

```
struct my_class {
    uint64_t value;
}

template<class T>
constexpr T operator/(const my_class& a, const my_class& b)
{
    return static_cast<T>(a.value) / static_cast<T>(b.value);
}
```

How can one select `a / b` (where `a` and `b` are of `my_class` type) to return `int` or `double`, for example?

Comment: Select based on what?

Comment: change `constexpr T operator/` to `constexpr int operator/`?

Comment: @appleapple I want sometimes get `double` and sometimes get `int`.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe That is the question indeed :)

Comment: `std::enable_if` and multiple definitions/overloads for `operator/`, me thinks.

Answer (score 5):

You could with a bit of template magic and conversion operators. You can first define a simple wrapper for your expression:

```
struct DivideMyClass {
    DivideMyClass(const MyClass& lhs_, const MyClass& rhs_) : lhs{lhs_}, rhs_{rhs} {}

    template<typename T>
    operator T () const {
        return static_cast<T>(lhs.value) / static_cast<T>(rhs.value);
    }

private:
    const MyClass& lhs;
    const MyClass& rhs;
};
```

Then, overloading the operator can be done like this:

```
constexpr DivideMyClass operator/(const my_class& a, const my_class& b)
{
    return DivideMyClass{a, b};
}
```

Then your code will look like this:

```
double d = MyClass{21} / MyClass{5}; // will be equal to 4.2
```

## Why this solution is bad

The language is not overloading division by the return type. You code will confuse other thinking there's a bug. If you use this method extensively, you will end up in an alomost unreadable code.

Another thing, the conversion is done implicitely, and there's nothing that says if there really was a conversion done in the operator on call site.

You will prevent the AAA idom (Almost Always use Auto). `auto` may break your code, and it's a bad thing.

Techniques like this should be use for template expression and stuff like that. Using that for simple division will confuse other.

Comment: Will `auto` work if I write in proxy class `template <typename T = double>`, for example?

Comment: No. Auto won't do any conversion. Auto will deduce the type of the expression following the `=`.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I select based on type of variable accepting the result? I.e. int
>   result = a/b returns int, but double result = a/b returns double?

If you are hell-bent on doing this you can, but it's complicated and I wouldn't recommend it. You have to careful weight the benefits vs the complexity introduced. You can do this via lazy evaluation:

```
struct X {
  int value;
};

struct X_op_proxy {
  const X& lhs;
  const X& rhs;

  template <class T>
  operator T() const { return static_cast<T>(lhs.value) / static_cast<T>(rhs.value); }
};
auto operator/(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) -> X_op_proxy
{
    return {lhs, rhs};
}

int main()
{
  X x1{11}, x2{2};

  int i = x1 / x2;
  cout << i << endl;

  float f = x1 / x2;
  cout << f << endl;
}
```

This is the minimum so you can figure out what this technique is about. You can adapt it and grow it to your needs.

Comment: Wow! Great! I thought it's impossible :-) That's why I'm asking so stupid (on first view) questions here :-) Thanks!

Comment: Why not simply `X_op_proxy operator/(const X& lhs, const X& rhs)`?

Comment: @W.F. Just an alternative syntax, doesn't matter.

Comment: bolov, is it possible to do this for `auto i = x1 / x2` to return `double` (for example) by default?

Comment: @vladon you could do explicit cast `auto i = (double)(x1/x2);`

Comment: @vladon but I believe defaulting template nor overloading cast operator won't end up in desired behaviour

Answer (score 2):

To choose a specific operator template, you must call it as a function:

```
auto result = operator/<double>(my_class{4}, my_class{2});
// result is 2.0
```

Comment: Yeah, but it's bad. Can I select based on type of variable accepting the result? I.e. `int result = a/b` returns `int`, but `double result = a/b` returns double?

Comment: @vladon no, you can't

Comment: @vladon what you could do is lazy evaluation with a proxy class. But it's too much work